# Stopping a page waiting for a usercontrol to finish loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way of stopping the main page waiting for a usercontrol to load before it can finish loading?

I have a usercontrolthat has to do a lot of DB calls which can take a few seconds making the page slow to load. 
Ideally I'd like the main page to load straight away and then the usercontrol content appear when it is ready.

I can't think of a way of doing this!

Help!

Bex

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. It's called AJAX ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX ). There is no way to do that in a single request though.

Additionally you can make the database calls asynchronous (Begin/End methods) and start the calls on some early stage in the control lifecycle and then end the request on a later stage. This way ASP.NET can go on processing your page while at the same time waiting for the database to respond. Depending on your logic workflow and timings this can reduce the load time in half or do nothing.

Comment: Async will not improve the page load time. In fact async does not improve load times, what it does (if done correctly which includes making the page async as well) is it frees up the request thread (using I/O completion ports) so IIS can use it to respond to other requests thereby improving the throughput of the site. The browser that made the original request will still wait for the response which will take the time it takes currently.

Comment: You are referring to asynchronous pages. I am referring to asynchronos database requests and these are quite different things. If the database requests take for example 1 second and can be made at the start of the page lifecycle and if the other stages of the lifecycle for the other controls on the page take a second you can gather the async results from the database queries later in the lifecycle and reduce the load time in half. Of course most code does not meet these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Unless you use ajax to request the contents that take a long time to generate.
You must understand that both controls and pages are processed by the server and the only thing returned to the browser is html. Nothing is sent to the browser before the entire page (including all controls) have been processed.

Comment: Is that last sentence correct or can you still do things like response.flush to start the data going to the client before it is all rendered. This would not work in all rendering models of course but I'm just curious if it is still possbile. I'd agree that Ajax would be the best way to go for this though.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question and how you want things to work is no. The "page" is a server side thing and it will need to complete processing before the browser sees it.

However, in order to achieve what you're looking for, you could use JavaScript in your browser (AJAX) to make another call to the server which then sends back only that piece of data probably as a JSON array or XML document which you then have to parse and construct html out of in order to display it. Or your response could be html that you can directly insert into the DOM.

A simple way to get the response you desire is to build another page that hosts this control and the markup of the page has no other html except for the control itself. You can make an AJAX call to this page and the response will be the html the control generates. You take that html and insert it into the DOM where you want it to be. Of course in your AJAX call you'll also need to send any parameters this other page will need so the control can do it's part.

I'm afraid, if you're new to AJAX and DOM then all of this will sound very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the DynamicPopulate control in the Ajax Control Toolkit.

You can find a sample here: [DynamicPopulate](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/DynamicPopulate/DynamicPopulate.aspx)